# Prax URL for Rack app does not work:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am setting up a VM using Vagrant/VirtualBox and want to access the apps in the VM from the host using Prax.

I have the following links added in .prax folder

```
*service.app.vm.dev.domain                      '~/app_folder'
*service.app                                    '~/app_folder'
```

vm name is of the format xx-xx-xx

I have also added an entry in host's /etc/hosts
as

```
IP Address service.app.vm.dev.domain.com
```

But I am still not able to hit the VM's app with the above URL

I have verified that ping to the guest's IP address works
I have verified that ping to the guest's domain name works
I have verified spinning the app server at port 9292 and accessing it from my host browser and get the status page.

So why would the host name URL not work as expected?